# i use factor(n) in matlab but it don't work for numbers like ((10^11-1)/11),for same number what can i do?

Tags: matlab, largenumber

I use `factor(n)` in matlab but it don't work for numbers like  `((10^11-1)/11)` - what can I do? My source is here.

```
m=input('Enter your number: ');
i=0;

while (i<m)
    if(isprime(i))
     % sum=factor((10^(i-1)-1));
        sum=factor((10^(i-1)-1)/i);
        disp(sum);
    end
    i =i+1;

end
```

but  for large n it returns errors!!

> ```
> >> FactorGen
>
> Enter your number: 45
>
>  3     3
>
>  3     3    11
>
>  3     3    11   101
>
>  3     3     3     7    11    13    37
>
>        3           3          11          41         271        9091
>
>        3           3           3           7          11          13          37         101        9901
>
> Error using factor (line 26) When n is single or double, its maximum
> allowed value is FLINTMAX.
>
> Error in FactorGen (line 7)  sum=factor((10^(i-1)-1));
> ```

I want the function `factor((10^(i-1)-1))` to work for same number. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: `10^11 - 1` is too big for that function to handle.  That's what the `FLINTMAX` error means.  However, I can't reproduce your error, using `factor(10^11 - 1)` gives me: `[3 3 21649 513239]`.

Comment: please run the source that i share top,and n input enter 45 ,you will see errors.

Comment: why is there no division in your code that corresponds to the `/11` in your title and first line of your question?

Comment: because this number (10^(i-1)-1) is devidable to   i ,that i is prime and no difference between  is 1/i,or not be 1/i,this is related to math theory Fermat's little theorem

Comment: I find it a bit tongue and cheek with your user name... `stackprogrammer` where this error is most likely due to what your name suggests.

Comment: @rayryeng i offer you see this link http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/programmer?s=t   for US English programer and programmer is true.but i confess that programmer is most used in books.but my teacher talked that both of them is true.

Comment: @stackprogramer I was talking about `stack` :)... you are probably performing a Stack Overflow and that's why you're getting that error.

Comment: why stack is error?my means of stack   is term in assembly for data structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be partially alleviated by converting your large number into `uint64` format. For R2014b maximum integer that can be handled is:

```
n = intmax('uint64')
n = 1.8447e+19
```

While the maximum `double` that can be handled is:

```
n = flintmax('double')
n = 9.0072e+15
```

This can be verified by simple example. Let's use `factor` on the number larger than `flintmax`. First, try `double`:

```
factor(10^16)
Error using factor (line 26)
When n is single or double, its maximum allowed value is FLINTMAX.
```

Now, we try `uint64`:

```
factor(uint64(10^16))
ans =  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

So, using `factor(uint64(x))` increases your limit by several orders. Indeed, there's no sense in using `double` format for `factor` function.

By the way, since using `factor` on large numbers may freeze your system, I suggest using this function:

```
function f = Factorize(n)
i = 0;
while mod(n,2) == 0
    i = i + 1;
    n = n/2;
    f(i) = 2;
    disp([2,n])
end
q = round(sqrt(double(n)));
q = q + 1 - mod(q,2);
for j = 3:2:q
    while mod(n,j) == 0
        i = i + 1;
        f(i) = j;
        n = n/j;
    end
end
if n > 2;
    i = i + 1;
    f(i) = n;
end
```

It is much faster for large numbers and does not overload the system at large n
Hope that helps

Comment: factor(uint64(10^16))    It works for 18digit number for large number is not work.

Comment: but your second source f():                                                                              f(99999999999999999999999999):.........................the result  ans =

   1.0e+15 *

  Columns 1 through 12

    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000

  Columns 13 through 24

    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000

  Columns 25 through 36

it don't work.

Comment: @stackprogrammer I said that the problem is partially alleviated, not completely solved. Using uint64 we just push the boundaries several orders up

Comment: @stackprogrammer and the number 99999999999999999999999999 is almost of order 26 that cannot be handled by Matlab. The number is perceived by Matlab as 1e26: `sprintf('%30d',99999999999999999999999999)` -> `1.000000e+26`
The only thing the provided function does is to speed the factorization up for large numbers. But it does not increase the number limit.